# Error is not showing using different controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

In my task show page, I have form for creating a response and the responses are displayed here as well. (Task has many responses)

views\tasks\show.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for([@task, Response.new]) do |f| %>
        <%= f.input :is_comment, as: :hidden %>
        <%= f.input :negotiate_pay, label: false %>
        <%= f.input :comment_text, as: :text, input_html: {rows: 3}, label: false %>


        <div class="row"> 
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-8">
                <%= f.button :submit %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <% end %>
    <br>
    <div id="comments">
        <%= render @responses %>
    </div>
```

controllers\tasks_controller

```
def show
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    @responses = @task.responses.all
end
```

controllers\responses_controller

```
def create
    @task = Task.find(params[:task_id])
    @response = @task.responses.create(response_params)
    @response.user_id = current_user.id
    @response.is_comment = params[:is_comment]
    @response.save
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to @task }
        format.js
    end
end
```

It is working alright but it doesn't show the errors in the form after validation and submit. How can I show the error message in response form which is in the show page of task. I am using a simple_form btw.

Help please

EDIT:

Models:
models\response.rb

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :task
has_many :subcomments
default_scope -> { order('created_at DESC') }

#VALIDATIONS
validates :comment_text, presence: true
validates :negotiate_pay, presence: true
```

Comment: Can you show your model code (or at least the validation portion)?  I'm assuming your model is derived from ActiveRecord?  Also, you need to display the error content somewhere in your view (see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html, section 8.).  If you're not using ActiveRecord, please edit your OP to describe how the errors are generated.

Comment: tnx for the reply. yes it is. I have included the model response. Please see my edit. tnx

Comment: Thx. Then I agree with the answer given by @RailsOuter (at least in principle).  His answer and the doc from my earlier comment should get you on the right track.

Comment: Hi again, I have a problem, see railsouter's answer, i got an error on format.html { render :show } on create action else statement.  Its giving me an error, Template is missing. I tried format.html { render 'tasks/show' } and it still result to an error ArgumentError in Responses#create. How do you render this correctly?

Comment: Try `{ render 'tasks/show', @task }` or even `redirect_to :show, @task`  (I'll back off  -- @RailsOuter is giving you good advice).

Comment: tried it, still no luck. well if i use redirect_to, the error wont be captured at page reload will it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the code that will display the errors to your form :

```
<%= simple_form_for([@task, Response.new]) do |f| %>
  <% if @response.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@response.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this response from being saved:</h2>
      <ul>
      <% @response.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

and you also need to tweak your `create` action in the responsesController:

```
def create
    @task = Task.find(params[:task_id])
    @response = @task.responses.build(response_params)
    @response.user_id = current_user.id
    @response.is_comment = params[:is_comment]
    respond_to do |format|
      if @response.save
        format.html { redirect_to @task, notice: "response was createad" }
        format.js
      else
        format.html { render :show }
    end
end
```

also make sure you are displaying the errors inside your application.html.erb :

```
<% if flash[:error] -%>
    <p class='alert alert-danger'><%=h flash[:error] %></p>
  <% end -%>
  <% if flash[:notice] -%>
    <p class='alert alert-success'><%=h flash[:notice] %></p>
  <% end -%>
```

Comment: tnx for the quick reply. i will try this now.

Comment: hi again,  see the format.html { render :show } in create action else statement. It results to an error, Template is missing. I tried format.html { render 'tasks/show' } and it still result to an error ArgumentError in Responses#create.

Comment: just try render @task

Comment: hi already tried that. still not working. It always result to template is missing. ie: the url should be like this: http://localhost:3000/tasks/12 but after the error th eurl looks like this http://localhost:3000/tasks/12/responses

Comment: when you try { render 'tasks/show' } whats the full error that you get?

Comment: I get this: ArgumentError in Responses#create ..............'nil' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object. It must implement :to_partial_path.

Comment: ArgumentError in Responses#create .....'nil' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object. It must implement :to_partial_path.   same result though..

Comment: ok I think I know I know the problem, you have some responses that are missing user_id. So you should clean you database, delete all tasks and responses and try again.

Comment: you can delete them from rails console.

Comment: hi again, i deleted tasks and responses, and i still do get all those errors. :(

Comment: I suggest you look up that error and see what you are doing wrong.